# Firebase refresh user record

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

With [Firebase.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), how do I refresh/refetch the user if the auth state hasn't changed?

I have an user who is authenticated with a phone number. I send an email verification link to the user who clicks it. The link verifies the user email (updates the record), and shows a "continue" button which leads back to the app (via deeplink). When back on the app, I want to refretch the user record from Firebase so I can see if the user email is verified. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object you get back from the auth state observer, you can call its [reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) method.

Answer (score 1):

you can update information about an existing user by [User information update in firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user)  and if a user wants to add some new information after authentication so check [UserRecord.UpdateRequest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/UserRecord.UpdateRequest)

**refresh the user data**

```
reload ( ) : Promise < void >
```

[Refreshes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reload) the current user, if signed in.